# sqrt problem in c++

Tags: c++

Why are there errors here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x,y;
};

int distance (const Point& a,const Point& b){
    int k= sqrt(((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)));
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: distance, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  distance.cpp
1>d:\...\distance.cpp(13): error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\...\vc\include\math.h(589): could be 'long double sqrt(long double)'
1>          c:\...\vc\include\math.h(541): or       'float sqrt(float)'
1>          c:\...\vc\include\math.h(127): or       'double sqrt(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const int)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5):

There are three overloads of `sqrt` which take different parameters: `float sqrt(float)`, `double sqrt(double)` and `long double sqrt(long double)`.  You can see these in the compiler output.

If you call `sqrt` with an integer parameter, like `sqrt(9)`, an integer can be cast to **any** of those three types.  So which function should be called?  The compiler doesn't know.  It's ambiguous, so you get an error to force you to explicitly choose the overload you want.  Just cast the parameter to match one of the overloads like this: `sqrt(static_cast<float>(((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)))`.

Comment: Apparently the current situation with the C++ standard calls for sqrt(int) to convert to a double without overload warnings/errors.  See Shafik's answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19684955/446767  However, since compiler versions will vary, the cast to double might still be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

sqrt takes a double ( apparently various different doubles in your compiler) - you are passing it an int

just do sqrt( (double) .... )

Ok - to be more precise, sqrt() must take a floating point number - either a float or a double. For various historical reasons it's generally able to convert between different floating point types. The bit of your CPU doing the sqrt calculation is probably (assuming x86) doing the calculation in 80bits which is neither a float nor a double/

Comment: `sqrt` is _required_ to be overloaded for `float`, `long double` and `double` in C++.  (See 26.5 [lib.c.math])

Comment: ...and `float` is not "another `double`".

Comment: @You - it's just a double that been on a diet.

Comment: since c++11, one can pass an int to sqrt. Look up a cpp reference site, such as [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/)

Answer (score 4):

this should work

```
   float k= sqrt((float)((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)));
```

sqrt() does not take int as a parameter.

Comment: Use double in preference to float. Why give away accuracy and the FPU is probably going to operate on a double anyway then throw away the precision converting back to float.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot take the sqrt of an integer. It needs to be a floating point number.

You need to do something like this:

```
int k= (int)sqrt((double)((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)));
```

The (double) will convert the int to a double ant the (int) converts it back to an int afterwards. You should also consider whether or not you want to use doubles consistently.

Answer (score 0):

There are three sqrt-methods: One that takes a long, one that take a float and one that takes a double value.

Try

```
 int k= (int)sqrt((double)(((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y))));
```

to tell the compiler that you want to use the double version and then convert back to int.

Answer (score 0):

You're in effect passing an `int` to `sqrt`, which only takes arguments of type `float`, `double` or `long double`. Additionally, `sqrt` doesn't return an `int`. The compiler can't guess what type conversion to make, so you'll have to cast it yourself either using C-style casts or "new style" casts:

```
float k = sqrt((float)(...));
float k = sqrt(static_cast<float>(...));
```

Also, indent your code properly; it makes reading it much easier.

Comment: What's `std::dynamic_cast` ??!!  And `dynamic_cast<float>` ?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't work on a type with no virtual functions. This should be `static_cast`.

Comment: Almost. `static_cast` is part of the language, not the `std` namespace. Drop the `std::`.