# Why does sqrt() work fine on an int variable if it is not defined for an int?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc4, gcc-4.2

In chapter 3 of *[Programming: Principles and Practice using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/index.html)* (sixth printing), Stroustrup states (p.68): **"Note that `sqrt()` is not defined for an `int`"**.

Here is a simple C++ program based on that chapter:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    cout << "Square root of n == " << sqrt(n) << "\n";
}
```

Given the quote above, I would expect the process of compiling or running this program to fail in some way.

To my surprise, compiling it (with g++ (GCC) 4.2.1) and running it succeeded without errors or warnings, and produced the following perfectly decent output:

```
Square root of n == 1.73205
```

My question therefore is: if `sqrt()` really is not defined for an `int`, then why doesn't the program above fail somehow?

Comment: You are doing what he said without knowing it. Your `int` is being implicitly converted to a `double`. I think he is recommending using a `double` explicitly, to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: Your software is doing an **implicit conversion**. As a guideline I always recommend avoiding implicit conversions - if a function takes a `double`, pass exactly a `double` to it, and nothing else.

Comment: @Max Because I can't be bothered to explain implicit type conversions and function overloading in the level of detail needed to make what I think would be a good answer, or do the background checking to make sure I am correct about which conversions are happening. If someone else wants to spend that time, or post a half-arsed answer, that is up to them.

Comment: See section 3.9.1 "Safe Conversions", p. 79.

Comment: Closely related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators

Comment: @AndreyT I don't think the dups answer is correct though, since there are multiple overloads and with an explicit case for integer values it would be ambiguous.

Comment: @BoBTFish there are three floating point overloads, without an explicit overload that covers the integer case it would be ambiguous.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Correct, sorry. I'm still in the habit of assuming people don't have `C++` support - we are in a stagnant state of `C++03` here :(

Comment: @Max And as it turned out, but not putting in the time to think about it carefully, I was wrong!

Comment: @BOBTFish Looks like an answer would have been better then, since then people could downvote it or you could edit it to be more correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Very good lesson for a beginner.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour: You are right, but as you correctly noted in your answer the new spec intends to keep the legacy code valid, i.e. `int` arguments should "somehow" resolve to `double` overloads without triggering overload ambiguity error.

Comment: This question was merged with another exact duplicate, I updated my answer to be a bit more specific and as far as I can tell more correct as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqrt() of int type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178618/sqrt-of-int-type-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2**

This question was merged with an exact duplicate, on taking a look at this, the actual answer is much simpler than anyone originally thought. The current version of [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) includes the following line:

```
inline double sqrt(int x) { return sqrt(double(x)); }   // to match C++0x
```

which creates a specific overload for the *int* case to match what modern compilers should be be doing which is *cast integer arguments to double*, although this version does not cover all the cases.

If *std_lib_facilities.h* was not being used than the original logic still applies, although `gcc-4.2` is rather old compared to *Visual Studio 2012* from the original question but a `4.1.2` version have uses `__builtin_sqrt` specifically for the integer case.

**Original**

Since around *2005* the draft standard required *integer* argument to be *cast* to *double* this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf). If we look in section `26` *Numerics library* and then go to section `26.8` *C library* which covers the `<cmath>` header, it specifies overloads of the math functions for *float*, *double* and *long double* which is covered in paragraph *8*:

> In addition to the double versions of the math functions in , C++ adds float and long double overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.

which would be `ambiguous` for the `int` case but the standard requires that sufficient overload are provided so that *integer* arguments are *cast* to *double*. It is covered in paragraph *11* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> > 1. If any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> > 2. Otherwise, if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, **then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to double.**
> > 3. Otherwise, all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters have type float.

**Update**

As @nos points out it is possible that the version of `sqrt` being called is from `math.h` header as opposed to the overloads from `cmath`, if that is the case and there is likely a *implementation defined* caveat here then we *may* be reverting to old *C style* behavior if the only version available is `sqrt(double)` which would mean that *int* would be converted to *double implicitly*.

One way I found to test this on `gcc` and `clang` would be to use *long* type for `a` which along with `-Wconversion` flag triggers a warning for a potentially value altering conversion on my platform if we only have `sqrt(double)` available. Indeed if I include `math.h` instead of `cmath` we can produce this warning. Although I can not trigger this behavior in *clang* which seems to indicate this is *implementation dependent*.

Comment: In the current standard, the relevant section is [cmath.syn]/2 "For each set of overloaded functions..."

Answer (score 5):

The 10 is being implicitly converted to a double. This will happen automatically as long as you have the correct function prototype for sqrt.

Edit: beaten by comments

Comment: There are three floating point overloads, which would be ambiguous and an error so there must be an explicit overload for integer cases.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour: You are right, but as you correctly noted in your answer the new spec intends to keep the legacy code valid, i.e. `int` arguments should "somehow" resolve to `double` overloads without triggering overload ambiguity error.

Comment: @nos That could be possible if the `math.h` is being used instead of `cmath` but if `cmath` if being used then I don't think that would be the case but that is probably implementation defined, let me amend my answer to cover both cases. Good point, thanks for pointing out the possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Because of *implicit conversions*. `sqrt` is defined for `double`, and an `int` value can be (and is) converted implicitly to a value of type `double`.

(It is in fact pretty hard to *prevent* a function that takes a `double` from being called with an `int`. You may get your compiler to emit a warning, but since this is typically a value-preserving conversion, even that may be hard. C++ inherits from C the design to try as hard as possible to make code work, even if it requires contortions. Other languages are much stricter about this sort of thing.)

Comment: About your second paragraph, wouldn't just putting in an overload of `sqrt(int) = delete` do it? I know a C++11 mention is coming, so how would that work differently from just not defining it in pre-C++11 apart from the nicer error?

Comment: @chris: I was speaking more generally. You can of course add individual overloads, but to cover all arithmetic types which are implicitly convertible to one another, you'd get into a mess. (Consider also having multiple arguments.)

Comment: Good point on the multiple parameters, though from testing a bit, the single parameter one seems to work pretty well with all built-in integral types.

Answer (score 2):

`sqrt` is defined for `double`. And C++ allows you to convert `int` to `double` implicitly.

```
int n = 3;
double x = sqrt(n);    // implicit conversion of n from int to double
```

Implicit conversions may happen when you use the value as a function parameter or assign it to a variable.

An example for the second case would be:

```
int n = 3;
double x = n;          // implicit conversion of n from int to double
```

Note that operators are also simply functions. Thus, you can also add an `int` to a `double`, which converts the `int` to a `double` before invoking the actual addition:

```
int n = 3;
double x = 1.0;
double sum = n + x;    // implicit conversion of n from int to double
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.

With the conversion, your code would look like this:

```
cout << "Square root of n == " << sqrt((double)n) << "\n";
```

Comment: Do you mean, `cout << "Square root of n == " << sqrt(double(n)) << "\n";` ?

Comment: @sampablokuper, Both of those do the same thing.

Comment: @sampablokuper I wrote the conversion with C syntax, you wrote it in C++ syntax (I'm just used to the first form).

Comment: @xorguy, I wouldn't really call it C++ form, seeing as how C++ also has `static_cast` et al (which are recommended over both of these). The proper name for it is a functional (function-style) cast.

Comment: @chris thanks for clarifying :) I'm having a look now at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler is actually automatically (i.e. "implicitly") converting the integer to a `double` (or maybe `long double`) and sending that value to `sqrt()`. This is completely normally and completely legal.