# Error "call of overloaded 'sqrt(int&)'

Tags: c++, cmath

[image]

So I'm just starting off in C++ reading the book "C++ without fear second edition" and I'm doing one of the examples which has me write this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
  using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  int i;
  int is_prime = true;

  cout << "Enter a number and press enter: ";
  cin >> n;

  i = 2;
  while (i <= sqrt(n)) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      is_prime = false;
    }
    i++;
    if (is_prime) {
      cout << "Number is prime" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Number is not prime" << endl;
    }
  }
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;

}
```

However when I attempt to compile I get the error

> 14 C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\C++\PrimeCheck.cpp
>   call of overloaded `sqrt(int&)'

Comment: Advice -- there is no need to post an entire program showing `while` loops, I/O,  and `system` calls to show us you're having problems calling the `sqrt` function.  A two or 3 line `main()` program would have shown the issue.

Comment: Also, *"call of overloaded"* is not a proper error message. Please post an MCVE and the actual error you get.

Comment: Does [this program compile successfully](https://ideone.com/meKcnY)?  If not, then you need to tell us what compiler you're using.

Comment: Duplicate question, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217970/1699328

Comment: I'm using the Dev-C++ compiler (or whatever compiler comes installed with that IDE.)

Comment: Edited with an image of the error.

Comment: @Dom If it's a duplicate, use "flag" to mark it as a duplicate.